# Frame exit operation Java

Tags: java, swing

How it could be done: If user pushes "escape" button on keyboard, then executes the code as user pushes on the frame's exit button?

So I have something like:

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == 27) {
    if (true) {
        /..
    } else {
    // Program behaves so, like the exit button in 
        // the frame was pushed
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just google for this... e.g. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JFramethatcloseswhensomeonepressestheESCkey.htm

Comment: @MikeSamuel this is swing!

Comment: @nachokk Not just swing. It's Java too. :)

Comment: I already flagged Mikes comment since it's completely wrong regarding topic and language.

Comment: @nachokk, My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Read about [How to use keybindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  In simple way to say, you bind a key to an specific action. In your case for example:

```
 String key = "ESCAPE";
 KeyStroke escapeKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);
 Action escapeAction = new AbstractAction() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.dispose();
         }
    };
 frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(escapeKeyStroke, key);
 frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put(key, escapeAction);
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer: the vm shuts down after the last frame is closed, so there is no need to call `System.exit()`.

Comment: @JensPiegsa I would say that's contextual, not bad advice, just contextual. Besides, the JVM will shutdown when all non-daemon threads have exited ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: context may vary. try to test it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Typically one would let the user choose, what should happen:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CloseVetoFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CloseVetoFrame frame = new CloseVetoFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public CloseVetoFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                requestExit();
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                shutdown();
            }
        });
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == 27) {
                    requestExit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void requestExit() {
        System.out.println("Window close requested.");
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Exit?") == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            dispose();
        }
    }

    protected void shutdown() {
        System.out.println("Window closed.");
    }
}
```

You should combine this with nachokks key binding approach.

Comment: `KeyListener`s have focus issues which means that unless the content pane is focusable AND has focus, the escape key will never be registered...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I updated the answer according to your advice. :-)